# Google Compute Engine cost for each VM Instance separately

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, price

I couldn't find any info about how or it is possible to get the monthly price for each VM Instance separately on Google Cloud Compute Engine.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Right know you can retrieve only billing information about the cost of the VM per machine type and region, but not for a specific VM.

What you are looking for  is under developement at the moment and you can star [the corresponding feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/36740620) to get notifications.

Answer (score -1):

1- Select or create a Cloud Platform project.
https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager?_ga=2.37436901.-491760448.1509366892?

2- Enable billing for your project.
https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6293499#enable-billing?

Comment: Click the Recommendations button on the top-right corner to toggle recommendations on or off. If there is a blue bar at the bottom of the button, recommendations are enabled:

Comment: I'm not sure if this is under Billing --> Transactions? Or? Thanks